# Datatables multible column sorting not work

Tags: jquery, mysql, datatables

I've HTML table

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Address</th><th>Phone</th><th>Email</th></tr></thead>
    <tfoot><tr><th>Name</th><th>Address</th><th>Phone</th><th>Email</th></tr></tfoot>
</table>
```

and jquery blugin from datatables.net

```
$('#example').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "orderMulti": true,
    "aaSorting": [ [0,'asc'], [1,'asc'] ],
    "ajax": {
        url: "data.php",
        "type": "POST"
    }
}).fnSort( [ [0,'asc'], [1,'asc'] ] );
```

And problem is that how to put work multiple table sorting. If i click i click address table clicked. I want to clicking the address title it change its sort and remain name sort. But clicking one table, and other sorting is losing. See an image. In sql query order by name desc, address asc never work.
Thank you
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have server side sorting enabled:  https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/

Are you actually doing any sorting on the server side?

Comment: I would need to see the json data you're sending back from the server.  See the documentation on server side processing.  It needs to be in a certain format,

Comment: echo jsonEncode(DB::query("SELECT name,city,phonenumber,contactEmail FROM mytable ORDER BY phonenumber asc  LIMIT 0, 100 "));
I want in a click event a query part "order by phonenumber asc, city desc, name asc" not only "order by name asc". But probably the datatables js-blugin doesn't enable it.

Comment: json data please.  Use your browser debugger to grab the network traffic.  In the meantime, I would consider turning server side off.

Comment: The datatables sents this json:
{"draw":"8","columns":[{"data":"0","name":"","searchable":"true","orderable":"true","search":{"value":"","regex":"false"}},{"data":"1","name":"","searchable":"true","orderable":"true","search":{"value":"","regex":"false"}},{"data":"2","name":"","searchable":"true","orderable":"true","search":{"value":"","regex":"false"}},{"data":"3","name":"","searchable":"true","orderable":"true","search":{"value":"","regex":"false"}}],"order":[{"column":"1","dir":"asc"}],"start":"0","length":"5","search":{"value":"","regex":"false"}}

Comment: And receive that json.
{"sEcho":0,"iTotalRecords":"1298","iTotalDisplayRecords":"1298","data":[["GT A..","Aav..","",""],["Aav..","Aav..","",""],["Aava..","Aav..","",""],["Nest..","Ahm..","",""],["Ahve..","Ahv..","",""],..]}

Comment: Thank you Brian. I found it. It's works if holding a Shift key down and then click.